# Calling ActionMode finish() in onConfigurationChanged() can lead to redraws

Tags: android, android-actionmode, onconfigurationchanged

I have an `ActionMode` in my fragment that I want only to run in the portrait mode; so I called `actionMode.finish()` in the `onConfigurationChanged()` fragment callback to stop the ActionMode if the orientation in the landscape:

```
override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
    if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        actionMode.finish()
}
```

This does work but Android studio warns me that **"Calling finish() within onConfigurationChanged() can lead to redraws"**.

Is there a better way to finish the ActionMode in landscape without having to worry about that redrawing?

Answer (score 0):

For example you have two activities: `MainActivity` and `SecondActivity`.

Attributes in `Manifest` should be:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
...
<activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
...
```

`MainActivity` starts `SecondActivity` when screen is rotated into `LANDSCAPE`:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(@NonNull Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

  if (ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE == newConfig.orientation) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class));
  }
}
```

`SecondActivity` checks on create if current orientation is `LANDSCAPE`, otherwise it finishes:

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT == getResources().getConfiguration().orientation) {
      finish();
      return;
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);
    ...
  }
```

When attribute `configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` is not present - activity will be recreated on each screen rotation, otherwise - method `onConfigurationChanged` is called.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am starting an ActionMode in activity; not starting a brand new activity.